# How do I detect what version of HTTP a user-agent supports, using PHP?

Tags: php, http, user-agent

Sorry if this question seems a little basic for some of you, but my programming knowledge leaves a lot to be desired, to say the least!

What I would like to know is this: When a request is made to my web server, how do I detect the **version** of HTTP that the requesting user-agent supports (i.e. HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1)? The server-side scripting language that my server uses is PHP version 5.2.

Basically, I would like to use PHP to do something like this:

```
if(/* user agent is currently using HTTP/1.1 */) {
 // do this...
}
else {
 // do something else...
}
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The superglobal [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable generally contains this kind of information. In this case, you're interested in the `SERVER_PROTOCOL` entry:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1'){
    // Client is using HTTP/1.1
} else {
    // Client is using a different protocol (likely HTTP/1.0)
}
```

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] has it's problems... See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17640877/632951

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server):

> **'SERVER_PROTOCOL'**
>   Name and revision of the information protocol via which the page was requested; i.e. 'HTTP/1.0';

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your speedy response, Gumbo.

I did actually consider $_SERVER_PROTOCOL, but for some reason I thought the value it returned was what *my server* used? So, am I now right in thinking that the value of $_SERVER_PROTOCOL corresponds to the *requesting user-agent*?

Comment: @clarky_y2k: Yes, *SERVER\_PROTOCOL* is the protocol that the client used in the current request. Just try an HTTP/1.0 request and see the difference.

Comment: @clarky_y2k: variable $_SERVER_PROTOCOL is deprecated in new PHP vresions, use $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] instead it

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` will have the version of HTTP by which the page was requested. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).