# Why does $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] show HTTP/1.0 when the client spoke HTTP/1.1

Tags: php, apache, http, nginx

I'm trying to know the HTTP version the user used to connect to my server. The code at http://test.yccau.com (PHP 5.3.26 and Apache 2.2.24) looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
?>
```

For some reason, the page shows `HTTP/1.0` even when the request and response were both `HTTP/1.1`:

[image]

What may be causing the problem? How do we get the HTTP version the web-client use to connect to the server?

Comment: maybe you are using php V5.2 or below

Comment: @user why is that relevant, is it a known bug in older PHP versions? can you elaborate? Perhaps post a link?

Comment: @user2511414 How does PHP version affect the HTTP protocol

Comment: Check the *Preview* tab. It shows `HTTP/1.0`.

Comment: @AmalMurali, yes that is the content of the page. The connection is HTTP/1.1 yet $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] is showing the content as HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1. What may be causing the problem?

Comment: Doc says "There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these"  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I think this is the relevant part, but my C-Fu isn't good enough to analyze the situation -- https://gist.github.com/amalmurali/af2d908a027ce87f0bc6#file-thttpd-c-L284

Comment: What HTTP server are you running?

Comment: @You, apache 2.2.24 + nginx http://www.hosting24.com/blog/index.php?read=Better-performance%21-New-server-setup%3A-Apache-%2B-Nginx%21&id=12 provided by hosting24's silver package  http://www.hosting24.com/features.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem! You have two connections here because you have a end-point proxy in between. The request from your version of `nginx` to `apache` is going over HTTP 1.0.

```
CLIENT <---- (HTTP 1.1) ----> NGINX <----- (HTTP 1.0) ----> SERVER
```

Nginx [1.1.4 onwards](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version) supports `HTTP 1.1` to upstream servers.

Comment: Is there any way to get information regarding the direct user's connection?

Comment: If Nginx is acting as a proxy, do you mean that REMOTE_PORT / REMOTE_USER / REMOTE_ADDR are giving incorrect values?

Comment: @Pacerier you could pass `$server_protocol` to your backend like so: `proxy_set_header X-Request-Protocol $server_protocol` and then, on the PHP side, read `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUEST_PROCOTOL']`. That would give you actual protocol that was used to communicate with client.

Comment: Isn't this similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640877/why-does-serverserver-protocol-show-http-1-0-when-the-client-spoke-http-1 ?